# Not matching grok filter sequence in my complex ravendb log

Tags: logstash, kibana, ravendb, logstash-grok

```
2020-03-11 21:15:57.7745,Raven.Bundles.Replication.Tasks.ReplicationTask,Warn,Alert,Could not notify http://PREDPOD1LN5A/Crips/Blup.RavenDbServer/databases/Alert about sibling server being up & running,"System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.


2020-02-14 10:12:18.9123,Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer,Warn,,Error on request,"Raven.Abstractions.Exceptions.ConcurrencyException: PUT attempted on document 'personcenteredplans/215544' using a non current etag
time,logger,level,database,message,exception
time,logger,level,database,message,exception
```

Above is the two pattern, for which I am writing the grok filter *`%{DATA:time},%{DATA:msg},%{WORD:Severity},(?<Full Message>[^%]*), %{URI}`* `match` **grok** filter but it is not covering all the points sequentially.

Any suggestions or inputs on this.

Comment: Can you update your question with your grok configuration as it is in your logstash pipeline, the entire grok filter? Also, your  first message does not end with an URI, and your second message does not even have an URI, you need to have patterns to match everything in your message.